# How do I properly load a BufferedImage in java?

Tags: java, image, loading, bufferedimage

Okay, so I've been trying to load a BufferedImage using this code:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("test.png");
BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
```

This gives me a type cast error when I run it though, so how do I properly load a BufferedImage?

Comment: Even if you have reasons to use Toolkit over ImageIO, this isn't the best method to call, because it will hold on to the image even after you're done with it. A better method to call is Toolkit.createImage(URL url)

Comment: Cast fails with Oracle-Java 8: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use [`ImageIO.read()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) instead:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: If you're looking for a pure Java alternative to `ImageIO` (ex: security reasons), there is [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/)

Answer (score 6):

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\work\\files\\logo.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Probably not the best place to catch the exception.