# JasperReports API. Getting error when using Image in report: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want  to print a *JasperReports*'s report via Java.

So I wrote a code as follows

```
 try {
            String r ="C:\\ireport\\Foods.jrxml";
            JasperReport jr =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(r);
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

But when I run the program I got following error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : flower1.png
```

I searched about this error in jasper community but I can't get understand the way they have explained the solution since I'm atotally newbie to the programming.
So can anyone give me a solution please?

My jrxml had following code snippet

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA["flower1.png"]]></imageExpression>
```

Comment: Please post you jrxml creating a [mcve], I bet it contains a  flower1.png

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yep.You are correct.I found it.Now what should I do?

Comment: Alex has answered your question thoroughly use that method or pass an absolute path to jrxml (the absolute path is normally passed through parameter.). Furthermore consider to accept Alex answer, so future users can find it.

Answer (score 4):

The good way it to use report's parameter for passing the image. And I believe that passing image as *BufferedImage* object is a good choice in your case.

### The sample of usage

#### The Java code snippet

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
try (InputStream inputStream = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/flower1.png")) {
    parameters.put("flowerImage", ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(JRLoader.loadBytes(inputStream))));
} catch (JRException | IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load images", e);
}
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);
```

#### The snippet of jrxml file

```xml
<parameter name="logoImage" class="java.awt.Image"/>
...
<image scaleImage="FillFrame">
    <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="224" height="43"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{flowerImage}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

---

1. The more information about using images you can find [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/images/index.html#images)
2. Info about reading resources with *Java* and where to store it:

   - [Different ways of loading a file as an
     InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676250/876298)
   - [How to read properties file in web
     application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3160691/876298)
   - [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in
     servlet based
     application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161054/876298)
3. Info about how to read image with *Java*:

   - [How do I properly load a BufferedImage in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601274/876298)